# Ajustar un carousel que usa una cantidad impar de figuras

Tags: html, css, carrusel

Buen día a todos. Tengo un carousel que puede tener un número impar de figuras, quizá sea algo simple pero no comprendo como ajustarlas. He jugado con los ángulos y el ancho pero no logro resolverlo.

Si tengo una cantidad par de figuras por ejemplo 6 no hay problema:
[image: 6Figuras]

Y si tuviera 5 figuras queda un espacio:

[image: 5Figuras]

¿Hay alguna forma de ajustarlas para que el resultado se vea como si tuviera 6 figuras?

El ejemplo: [Carousel Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/democarrousel?file=index.html)

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="slideshow">
    <div class="entire-content">
      <div class="content-carrousel">
        <figure class="shadow">1</figure>
        <figure class="shadow">2</figure>
        <figure class="shadow">3</figure>
        <figure class="shadow">4</figure>
        <figure class="shadow">5</figure>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
#slideshow {
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 600px;
  width: 100%;
}
.entire-content {
  margin: auto;
  width: 240px;
  perspective: 1200px;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 80px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.content-carrousel {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  animation: rotar 15s infinite linear;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.content-carrousel figure {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}
.content-carrousel figure:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(240px);
}
.content-carrousel figure:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotateY(60deg) translateZ(240px);
}
.content-carrousel figure:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotateY(120deg) translateZ(240px);
}
.content-carrousel figure:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(240px);
}
.content-carrousel figure:nth-child(5) {
  transform: rotateY(240deg) translateZ(240px);
}
.shadow {
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px #000;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5rem;
}
@keyframes rotar {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
    z-index: 2;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ajusta la rotación para cubrir los 360 grados, actualmente rotas 60 grados cada elemento, al tener sólo 5 elementos, te estás quedando corto por 60. De todas formas, la solución real estaría en calcular la rotación de acuerdo al número de elementos, y establecer un número mínimo (por ejemplo 3) y uno máximo (digamos 12) de elementos en tu carrusel.

Answer (score 0):

Como mencionaba @Mauricio Contreras, tengo dos soluciones usando javascript y sass. Con javascript ejecuto una función que itera sobre cada hijo agregando la rotación según el incremento en grados. Dependiendo el número de hijos.

```
function startCarousel() {
  let nChild=document.getElementsByClassName('shadow');
  let iDegrees=360/nChild.length;
  for (let i of nChild) {
    document.querySelector('.content-carrousel figure:nth-child('+i.innerHTML+')')       
    .style.transform='rotateY('+i.innerHTML*iDegrees+'deg) translateZ(250px)';
  }
}
```

Y con sass sería algo similar, lo malo es que no se puede obtener el número de hijos de manera dinámica.

```
.content-carrousel {
  $iDegrees: 360deg / $nChild;
  @for $i from 1 through 5 {
    figure:nth-child(#{$i}) {
      transform: rotateY($i*$iDegrees) translateZ(250px);
    }
  }
}
```

Me gusta más la solución con sass aprovechando que estoy usando angular, pero por el momento no encuentro una manera de hacerlo como con javascript.